# Disabling spell checker in OpenOffice Calc (or LibreOfffice Calc)

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, spell-check

Is there a way to disable the spell checker in OpenOffice Calc (or LibreOffice Calc) **without disabling it for the other programs in the office suite**?

I would prefer to just disable it for a range of cells.  If that is not possible, disabling it for the entire spreadsheet would be acceptable.

I seem to remember a trick that involved changing the language for the cells to be one without spellchecking, but I do not recall the details of that trick, or if it possible with current versions.  ***Regardless, all solutions are welcome.***

Comment: Spell check is a global function that cannot be disabled for a single application or file.  This has led to some bug reports, for example [Issue 124396 - Auto-correct interfers with numeric evaluation](https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=124396)

Comment: @Lyrl Thanks.  That's quite a functionality deficit.  There used to be a technique, I believe it involved changing the language of the text, that would prevent spell-checking on any block of text.  A generous user here posted an answer involving this technique, but chose to delete that answer because his method didn't quite work (sorry, I can't see deleted posts).  I wonder if such a technique still exists, but requires a little more tweaking.

Comment: Amo's answer bumped this to the main page.  A potential workaround occurred to me.  You could look at using a macro that is either incorporated into each workbook via the standard template, or run at startup of Calc.  It would deselect spell checking.  Another macro would reselect it at closing, or the other office applications could have a similar macro at startup that selects it.

Comment: @fixer1234 Interesting idea.  I don't recall anymore.., does the macro functionality require JRE?

Comment: I have no idea.  Since switching to LO, I haven't needed to do any macros.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

In the uppermost menu bar go to -
Tools > Options > Language Settings > Writing Aids > Options.
Now deselect "Check spelling as you type", "Check grammar as you type"...

Comment: I tested this in LibreOffice, but it disables the spell checking in all the LibreOffice applications, not just LibreOffice Calc.  In which office suite did you test this?

Comment: I was unaware of that. It did the same for me, disabled spell checking from Writer too. BTW I had tested it in LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 1):

I (LO 5.1.6.2) set the language to "[None]" for the cells, and the spellchecker ignores them.

True, I DO get red lines under non-English words in all cells. Seems the Auto-Checking red-underliner tries with English for all cells, regardless of their set language.

But when actually running the Spellchecker, it just ignores the cells set to language "[None]".

Comment: With LibreOffice 7.1.3.2, this trick also gets me rid of the wavy red underlines. :-)

Comment: Advice: the best way to set the language to “[None]” for all cells of a document, in one go, is to set this option for the `Default` cell style (press F11). This avoids having dangling custom styles for particular cells, and having to fix that each time you move or create cells.

Answer (score 1):

#### tldr: use `shift+F7`

for graphical option, it depends. there is 7 different [user interfaces](https://books.libreoffice.org/en/IG72/IG7212-UserInterfaceVariants.html) in libreoffice:

two main user interfaces:

1. Standard Toolbar - the default menu bar - you can use `tools` > and toggle `automatic spell checking`
2. Tabbed - similar layout as ms.office. you can use `review` > and toggle `auto Spellcheck`

---

and 5 minor user interfaces:

3. Single Toolbar - same way as Standard Toolbar
4. Sidebar - same way as Standard Toolbar
5. Tabbed Compact - same as Tabbed
6. Groupedbar Compact - same way as Tabbed (Although it looks completely different)
7. Contextual Single - the same as Standard Toolbar